# Add Glare to a single object in composite? (Cycles)

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is it possible to add different glare nodes to different objects to give them varying glow effect in Cycles?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the *View Layer Properties*, under *Passes* > *Cryptomatte* you can enable *Object* and/or *Material* depending on if you want to separate the differing glare effects by object or material.

[image: cryptomatte passes]

If you now render the scene and go to the *Compositor* (with *Backdrop* enabled and a *Viewer* node to see the backdrop) you will notice some new "Crypto..." outputs on the *Render Layer* node. You can ignore them, they are legacy outputs and not necessary for the workflow.

Add a *Cryptomatte* node (important: not *Cryptomatte (Legacy)*!) which you'll find under *Mask* in the *Add* menu. There you can choose which cryptomatte layer you want to use with this node. Choose *ViewLayer.CryptoObject* if you want to separate by object or *ViewLayer.CryptoMaterial* to separate by material. Note that the name "ViewLayer" can change according to the actual name of your view layer.

After choosing *CryptoObject* or *CryptoMaterial*, you can click on the `+` Plus button and get an eyedropper tool to pick an object or material to add to the mask. When you hover over an object/material, there will be a tool tip giving the name of which one you are about to choose. You can add more than one but have to hit the Plus button for each.

After picking one more more objects or materials, the *Image* output of the *Cryptomatte* node will only output the selection with a transparent background. Now you can plug this into a *Glare* node. Adjust the glare effect settings to your liking. Then set the *Mix* value in the *Glare* node to 1. This way the node will only output the glare effect and nothing of the original image.

You can now add the glare effect onto the original image with a *Mix Color* node set to *Add*. By the way I use this method almost always because I have better control on how much the glare affects the image by not only reducing the *Fac* value for less glow, but you can also set a value higher than 1 which is not possible with the only the *Glare* node.

Here is an example where I masked the object "Cube" in the *CryptoObject* layer (which is the red one in the middle) to give it strong streaks with the *Glare* node which I then add to the original image. In the *CryptoMaterial* layer I picked "Material.002" which is the green material to give it a fog glow with a second *Glare* node. This affects the left cube and one half of the cube to the right. The blue material gets no effect because I neither picked the object itself nor the material.

[image: compisting example]

Comment: How would you go with cryptomatte in this kind of situation, because the blur doesn't work fine (we can see the original image behind): https://zupimages.net/up/24/05/mm19.jpg  https://blend-exchange.com/b/WzvSO9vS

Comment: @moonboots Simply put: I don't know, but most likely I would not do this with cryptomatte. Never said this would work for everything ;) The question was about using different _Glare_ nodes for different objects.

Comment: OK I was just curious if you knew how to fix that with cryptomatte   ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a floor, a red cube and a blue cube, put each object in its own collection. In the *Outliner* create 3 view layers, in each view layer make only one collection visible. In the *Render panel > Film*, enable *Transparent*. Render the image. In the *Compositor*, create 3 *Render Layers* nodes, in each one select one different view layer. Mix the *Render Layers* with a *Color > Mix > Alpha Over*, put a *Filter > Glare* node after the *Render Layers* nodes with the cubes.

Comment: I did the steps. I can get the mixed image but NOT the glare. A glare node is added after each cube's render layer and they are mixed with Alpha Over. Then Floor is mixed with the cubes with another alpha over.

Comment: For some reason I can't upload a picture in my answer but here is a screenshot of my material setup: https://www.zupimages.net/up/24/05/iq1f.jpg

Comment: I did the exact same thing. All 3 items on different render layers. but the glow isn't there.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/ use anotherplatform, like workupload, if the file is too heavy, or make it as light as possible

Comment: Why so complicated? Just use the _Cryptomatte_.

Comment: Yes this is the other solution, maybe give it as well

Comment: "The other solution"... okay, but how would you use the view layers to get this result: [different glare on different objects/materials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc6b1.png)? The good thing about cryptomatte (if you enable it) here is, you only have to render a single layer, you can decide after rendering which objects or materials you want to select directly in the compositor. And add new ones when changing your mind. All without the need to render again. And I guess the torus around the cube is problematic, too... Just curious how to do that with view layers ;)

Comment: No problem, I wasn't sarcastic, I was just wondering, I'm not very familiar with cryptomatte  ;)

Comment: No, all fine - I thought your solution was good at first, too. Have done things with view layers before as well. While they are helpful for some cases, for others they are not. For example the image I link to: reflections, shadows, bouncing light - that gets all very complicated when you want to combine this with view layers (even more when you select just parts of an object like the glow on the torus). And cryptomatte... well, there might be other uses for cryptomatte as well, but I think they are especially helpful for these effects where you can add on top of the original image.

Comment: Yes I guess the best solution will depend on the situation